# get id of hidden input field on select box change event

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i have a dynamic table where its rows data are shown with using foreach method.
i want to fetch the value of hidden input field on change of select box option.
this is my code,

```
@foreach($sCForms as $sCForm)
 <tr>
    <td>{!! $sCForm->Description !!}</td>
    <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" 
        value="{{$sCForm->id}}" id="hidden"></td>
    <td class="demo">
       <select name="assigned_to" id="assigned_to" class="demo form-control 
         required" style="width: 90%;" onchange="changeassigned()">
            <option value="">--Select user--</option>
              @foreach($users as $user)
                  <option value="{{$user->id}}">
                      {{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}
                  </option>
              @endforeach
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

my function:

```
 function changeassigned()
   {
       var id = $('#assigned_to').val();
       var form_id = $('.demo').parent().parent().find('input').val();
       alert(form_id);
   }
```

my problem with this code is i am getting value of first row hidden field only.

what is the best way to get value of every row's hidden field.?

Comment: Unless you foreach only returns 1 loop then you will have multiple elements with the same ID, that is a no go. An ID should always be unique. Second try use `changeassigned(this)` and then `function changeassigned(obj)
   {
       var id = $(obj).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd shall always be unique, never the less this should provide you with the result you want:

```
function changeassigned(obj) {
  var id = $(obj).val();
  var form_id = $(obj).closest("tr").find('input').val();
  alert(form_id);
}
```

**demo**

```js
function changeassigned(obj) {
  var id = $(obj).val();
  var form_id = $(obj).closest("tr").find('input').val();
  alert(id + " | " + form_id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>My Form</td>
      <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="FormID" id="hidden"></td>
      <td class="demo">
        <select name="assigned_to" class="demo form-control 
         required" style="width: 90%;" onchange="changeassigned(this)">
          <option value="">--Select user--</option>

          <option value="user1">
            user1
          </option>
          <option value="user2">
            user2
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>My Form2</td>
      <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="FormID2" id="hidden"></td>
      <td class="demo">
        <select name="assigned_to" class="demo form-control 
         required" style="width: 90%;" onchange="changeassigned(this)">
          <option value="">--Select user--</option>

          <option value="user3">
            user3
          </option>
          <option value="user4">
            user4
          </option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you  willl get elements with same "id" . change it to class or something =)

you can pass "this" to changeassigned function to get start point to you selector

Comment: How is this different from my comment?

Comment: same.. also in same time

Comment: Well I wrote my comment 2 min before you did.

Comment: take a cookie))

Comment: It about providing the OP with relevant Information and answers, but there is no need to provide multiple answers/comments that is basically the same. I just clarified that you said we wrote them at the same time, wish is basically not true.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Like this - using variable i, create dynamic id of hidden and select

{{ $i=0 }}
@foreach($sCForms as $sCForm)
 <tr>
    <td>{!! $sCForm->Description !!}</td>
    <td style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" class="hidden" 
        value="{{$sCForm->id}}" id="hidden{{ $i }}"></td>
    <td class="demo">
       <select name="assigned_to" id="assigned_to{{ $i }}" class="demo form-control 
         required" style="width: 90%;" onchange="changeassigned({{ $i }})">
            <option value="">--Select user--</option>
              @foreach($users as $user)
                  <option value="{{$user->id}}">
                      {{$user->first_name}} {{$user->last_name}}
                  </option>
              @endforeach
        </select>
    </td>
    {{ $i++ }}
</tr>
@endforeach


function changeassigned(i)
{
   var id = $('#assigned_to'+i).val();
   var form_id = $('#hidden'+i).val();
   alert(form_id);
}
```

Comment: You are still duplicating ID's !!

Comment: I forgot, please declare "$i = 0"

Comment: No You are still duplicating the `id="assigned_to"` same goes for your jquery function.

Comment: id="assigned_to{{ $i }}" then you should be change the select tag id dynamic, and try it.
may be solved

and in your js also change
var id = $('#assigned_to'+i).val();
instead of
var id = $('#assigned_to').val();

Comment: I'm not asking for a "how to do it" im just tell you that you have a mistake.